# Redirect after user has logged in

Tags: redirect, authentication, angularjs, angularjs-routing, angularjs-authentication

I'm pretty new to Angular, and right now I'm just trying to get all my routes set up and working as I'd like.

**Setup:**
When a user navigates to certain pages (`/settings` for this example) the app should check if there is a user already logged in.  If there is continue as usual.  Otherwise the user should go to the login page (`/login`).

**What I'd like:**
After the user has successfully logged in they should go to the page they were originally trying to get to (`/settings`)

**My question:**
Is there an "Angular way" to remember where the user was trying to go to?

**Relevant code:**

app.js

```
  .when('/settings', {
      templateUrl: '/views/auth/settings.html',
      controller: 'SettingsCtrl',
      resolve: {
        currentUser: function($q, $location, Auth) {
          var deferred = $q.defer();

          var noUser = function() {
            //remember where the user was trying to go
            $location.path("/login")
          };

          Auth.checkLogin(function() {
            if (Auth.currentUser()) {
              deferred.resolve(Auth.currentUser());
            } else {
              deferred.reject(noUser());
            }
          });

          return deferred.promise;
        }
      }
    })
```

login.js

```
  $scope.submit = function() {
    if(!$scope.logInForm.$invalid) {
      Auth.login($scope.login, $scope.password, $scope.remember_me)
      //go to the page the user was trying to get to
    }
  };
```

Much thanks to John Lindquist for [the video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P6KITGRQujQ) which got me this far.

Comment: You could store this information on $rootScope or in a [service](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First off, you do not want to redirect the user to a login page.

An ideal flow in a single page web app is as follows:

1. A user visits a web site.  The web site replies with the static assets for the
   angular app at the specific route (e.g. /profile/edit).
2. The controller (for the given route) makes a call to an API using $http, $route, or other mechanism (e.g. to pre-fill the Edit Profile form with details from the logged in user's account via a GET to /api/v1/users/profile)
3. If/while the client receives a 401 from the API, show a modal to
   login, and replay the API call.
4. The API call succeeds (in this case, the user can view a pre-filled Edit Profile form for their account.)

How can you do #3?  The answer is $http **Response Interceptors**.

> For purposes of global error handling, authentication or any kind of
>   synchronous or asynchronous preprocessing of received responses, it is
>   desirable to be able to intercept responses for http requests before
>   they are handed over to the application code that initiated these
>   requests. The **response interceptors** leverage the promise apis to
>   fulfil this need for both synchronous and asynchronous preprocessing.

[http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http)

Now that we know what the ideal user experience should be, how do we do it?

There is an example here:  http://witoldsz.github.com/angular-http-auth/

The example is based on this article:

http://www.espeo.pl/2012/02/26/authentication-in-angularjs-application

Good luck and happy Angularing!

Comment: I disagree with your statement about "not wanting to redirect". I'm using http interceptor to catch 401 & display login modal.It has one serious problem my client won't accept - on failed page there is visible portion of application - ng-view renders but components are empty cos of 401 requesting resources from API. But page (interface) is visible to totally unprivileged visitor too.